# How do I parse this JSON using JAVA

Tags: java, json

Hey guy's so am trying to parse this json to get all the sName

Am keep failing to get them all i can only manage to get only 1 sName not all in the json

Don't have any idea on what to do next i was thinking of doing a for statement for it?

Any ideas? or code example thanks!

Please note am using the JAVA json libary!

My code:

```
    String text = MainUI.json_text.getText();
    try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(text);
    Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        try {
            Object value = json.getString("sName");
            System.out.println(value);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed:" + e.toString());
        }
    }
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Quest_Json.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

JSON:

```
{
   "sFaction":"None",
   "iClass":0,
   "oRewards":{
      "itemsS":{
         "0":{
            "ItemID":"17109",
            "sLink":"",
            "sElmt":"None",
            "bStaff":0,
            "iRng":10,
            "bCoins":0,
            "iDPS":0,
            "sES":"None",
            "sType":"Item",
            "iCost":0,
            "iRty":10,
            "iQSValue":0,
            "iQty":10,
            "sReqQuests":"",
            "sIcon":"iibag",
            "iLvl":1,
            "bTemp":0,
            "bPTR":0,
            "iQSIndex":-1,
            "iStk":40,
            "sDesc":"Use this to merge into epic gear in the shop!",
            "bHouse":0,
            "bUpg":0,
            "bQuest":0,
            "sName":"Realm Gem"
         }
      }
   },
   "sField":"id2",
   "bOnce":1,
   "bStaff":0,
   "iValue":4,
   "iGold":1000,
   "oItems":{
      "17107":{
         "sIcon":"iibag",
         "ItemID":17107,
         "iLvl":1,
         "sLink":"",
         "sElmt":"None",
         "bTemp":1,
         "bStaff":0,
         "iRng":1,
         "bCoins":0,
         "iDPS":0,
         "sES":"None",
         "bPTR":0,
         "iQSIndex":-1,
         "sType":"Quest Item",
         "sDesc":"Well done, Hero!",
         "iStk":5,
         "iCost":0,
         "bUpg":0,
         "bHouse":0,
         "iRty":10,
         "sName":"Wolf Defeated",
         "iQSValue":0,
         "sReqQuests":2819
      }
   }
}
```

Result am getting :

Your Fifth Quest: Water Creature

Your Fifth Quest: Water Creature

Your Fifth Quest: Water Creature

Your Fifth Quest: Water Creature

Your Fifth Quest: Water Creature

And so on!

But it should get every sName not the same one always!

Comment: What are you using that causes you to "keep failing"?

Comment: Are you trying to parse it manually, or using an external library like GSON?

Comment: There are numerous answers to this question already. Use the search function.

Comment: Yes, we could use the Java code you're using now, as well as the full stack trace of any exception, and the version(s) of any libraries.

Comment: Don't try parsing Json manually - it's not that simple. Use a pre-existing library. Or, if you want to see how Json parsing works, study the source code of those libraries.

Comment: Please check the edit i posted my code and what library i use

Comment: Please describe your problem. Tell us what you expected to happen and what happens, in details.

Comment: Alright made it more specific sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Use GSON library or Jackson library to serialize/deserialize. There are a lot of examples all over the stack over flow.

GSON Example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Jackson example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

Comment: Actually, there are at least 20 different JSON packages for Java.  A list is available at json.org.